# Rails 4 Redirect flash notice to ActiveAdmin from REST API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

Hi i want to check a boolean in my REST `params` set through

```
if params[:myboolean] == true
  ...         
end
```

in my `api` controller and trigger an `flash[:alert]` event when the condition is `true` in my AciveAdmin board. How can i do that?

**EDIT**

```
 def update
     respond_to do |format|
        if params[:myboolean] 
              Rails.logger.info "***boolean is true***"           
        end
```

I never see the logger message. is the way i check the params already wrong?

**UPDATE**

I send the parameter through `curl -u test -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/...?myboolean\=true -d ''`  and it gets updated in my  database, so i think its not an issue with the parameter more with my way of checking the parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters are sent as strings be default, they are not always magically changed to bool/integers, therefore you'd have to change the check to:

```
if params[:myboolean] == 'true'
```

Note the quote marks, you're then com,paring like with like (both strings).

You may also have you boolean coming through as 1 or 0, so you might have to match for that too:

```
if ['true','1'].include? params[:myboolean].to_s
```

By doing to_s on the param, you're also ensuring that if it does come through as anb actual bool then the check will still work

Comment: Perfect! Now i at least can pass the test!  Thanks for bringing me closer to Ruby/Rails syntax/semantic

Comment: Your welcome. If this worked for you, please consider marking as answer then others will know what worked

Comment: Yes half of my question is answered ;) But i also would like to know how i can redirect the this to AA

Comment: Fair enough. I suggest you add a specific question about this as it's not clear from your current question

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this I usually do something like:

```
puts "params: #{params}"
```

Should print all the params sent to the method and you should see if your `params[:myboolean]` is set or not.

Comment: Thanks for the `puts` method. I included it but also do see nothing. But the boolean should be set since i send this specific parameter via `curl -u test -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/...?myboolean\=true -d '' `. And this boolean gets updated in my db accordingly, so i think it is set